# Re-syncing two servers after files have been deleted on one

Tags: windows, macos

We have a problem regarding two synced file servers, SERVER A and SERVER B.

For an error, in a period of 2 weeks, all files deleted on SERVER A were not deleted on SERVER B, so now I have to remove all deleted files in `SERVER B` after a given date X.

So, SERVER B is the master server, so after date X all files on SERVER B are *only* on SERVER B.

How can I do this?

Comment: Ah, the problem is now SERVER B is the master server, so AFTER date X all files in Server B are ONLY in server B.

Comment: I think you're missing the most important part: What operating systems are those servers running? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

For our office we use a tool called rsync:

http://rsync.samba.org/

Comment: Could you give the OP the necessary rsync commands to perform what they want?